# Pulling data from Java application to Salesforce, where should i start?

Tags: java, soap, salesforce, integration, database-metadata

I'm new in programming, and I'm trying to do a something like this.
I have data(Objects, Fields & Records) in a Java based web application. 
I need that data on salesforce.com. How do i achieve this? by diggin in stack for an hour i came across couple of solutions(A part of it though).

1. Using data export option in Salesforce, which is again manual, i dont know if there is a automate process.
2. Using SOAP api or Partner API

   - To get the objects : describeGlobal()
   - To get list of fields: describeSObjects.

Any ideas ? or suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you planing to have this transition one time or periodically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Data export functionality provided out of the box by salesforce allows your organization to generate backup files of your data on a weekly or monthly basis depending on your edition. It is mostly used for backup purposes.

2 - Is the upload process something triggered from the Java application itself ?
or you need some periodical data dump between your webapp and salesfoce ?

In the first case you have to use the SOAP API interface,directly inside your java code.

find below a good recipe from the cookbook:

> http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/calling-salesforce-web-services-using-apex

In the second case you can export your data into a csv file from your java app and load it in salesforce using the Dataloader. This process can be easily batched periodically.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I think i will dig more on 1st scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use SOAP API to load data into salesforce if the record limit <50000 . In case you want to load huge amount of data in salesforce, you can opt for a BULK API. For SOAP you need to have the Enterprise wsdl and for bulk - its Partner WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

We have experience with using SOAP API. I would suggest downloading soapUI tester and pulling the Enterprise WSDL from Salesforce, to get a feel for how to insert the data.

Also keep note of the governors and limits that SF imposes, in case you start trying to send data OUT of SF as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Everyone I have used bulk api of salesforce.With the help of bulk api We can fetch and insert upto 10000 record in one batch .So you can go with bulk api